# Cannot connect with SAS LIBNAME

Tags: oracle, sas

I can connect to schema and tables through TOAD, but when I try to connect through a SAS libname statement I get:

> libname JOED oracle user=XXX orapw=XXXXX path="XXXXX.World" schema=XXX;
>
> **ERROR: ORACLE connection error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>          specified.
>   ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.**

I have checked my TNSNAMES.ORA file and the server exists (like I said I can connect through TOAD)

I have also confirmed the connection through Data Sources (ODBC) - x86

Comment: I'm not convinced this isn't an Oracle error, so throwing that tag on just in case.  That error certainly suggests you aren't properly submitting your path correctly...

Comment: Actually, I would try it without the " " - those may need to either be left off, or be single quotation marks (').  Oracle doesn't consider (") to be the same as (') like SAS does.

Comment: This is an Oracle Error.  SAS is returning the error code, "ORA-12154".  This is usually a problem in the TNSNAMES file.  Random spaces used to cause problems.  It could also be a problem with client version and SAS version.  Regenerate the TSNNAMES file with the client wizard.  Check with support.sas.com for version incompatibilities.  I haven't used Oracle in a few years, or I could offer a more specific solution, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with TOAD, but e.g. Oracle SQL Developer uses different Oracle client components than SAS uses to connect to db, so it doesn't prove the setup is correct for SAS.

Try to connect using SQL Plus from the computer that runs SAS - that would be equivalent of what SAS does.

First, check the **exact case of the instance** specified in `TNSNAMES.ORA` and the `PATH` option in SAS libname, I've often seen that to cause the unexpected troubles.

`ORAPW=` option doesn't look familiar to me, should be `PW=` I guess, though that would cause different error message to me.